# Match elements of properties in objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, innerhtml

I've been trying to compare all the series from my objects with the corresponding genre. I managed to display them but I'm practically writing the same code three times, while I'm sure there is a better way.

I'm trying to figure it out how to make the "type" argument match the right genre with the right series, so I don't have to call the same function three times. Maybe I shouldn't use objects into an Array, idk.

Please ask me if there is anything confusying.

```
'use strict';

//LIST OF SERIES

let listSeries = 
[
    {film: ['Breaking Bad', 'One of Us Is Lying'], genre: "Drama"},

    {film: ['Servant', 'The Midnight Club'], genre: "Horror"},

    {film: ['The Office US','Seinfeld'], genre: "Comedy"}
]


// SERIES CLASS

class Series
{
    constructor(series, type)
    {
        this.series = series;
        this.type = type;
    }
}


//CLASS DISPLAY SERIES LIST WRTING HTML

class Display
{
    tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

    add(libraryOfSeries) 
    {
        let uiString = `<tr>
                            <td>${libraryOfSeries.series}</td>
                            <td class="table-dark">${libraryOfSeries.type}</td>
                            <button class="btn1 btn-primary" >Read!</button>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;
    }
}


// DISPLAY DRAMA SERIES AND CALLING THE ADD METHOD INTO THE CLASS DISPLAY

function displayDrama(series)
{
    let dramaSeries = series.find(item => item.genre == "Drama");

    for(let i of dramaSeries.film)
    {
        let currentSeries = new Series(i, dramaSeries.genre);

        let display = new Display;

        display.add(currentSeries)
    }
}

displayDrama(allSeries);


// DISPLAY COMEDY SERIES AND CALLING THE ADD METHOD INTO THE CLASS DISPLAY

function displayComedy(series)
{
    let comedySeries = series.find(item => item.genre == "Comedy");

    for(let i of comedySeries.film)
    {
        let currentSeries = new Series(i, comedySeries.genre);

        let display = new Display;

        display.add(currentSeries)
    }
}

displayComedy(allSeries);


// DISPLAY DRAMA SERIES AND CALLING THE ADD METHOD INTO THE CLASS DISPLAY

function displayHorror(series)
{
    let horrorSeries = series.find(item => item.genre == "Horror");

    for(let i of horrorSeries.film)
    {
        let currentSeries = new Series(i, horrorSeries.genre);

        let display = new Display;

        display.add(currentSeries)
    }
}

displayHorror(allSeries);
```

Comment: Use the `type` variable: `series.find(item => item.genre == type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a function with two input variables, then whenever you are trying to call that function, you can decide what you are going to filter.

```
function displayGenre(series, genreToFilter)
{
    let comedySeries = series.find(item => item.genre === genreToFilter);

    for(let i of comedySeries.film)
    {
        let currentSeries = new Series(i, comedySeries.genre);

        let display = new Display;

        display.add(currentSeries)
    }
}

// Calling the function to display drama:
displayGenre(allSeries, "Drama")

// Calling the function to display comedy:
displayGenre(allSeries, "Comedy")

// Calling the function to display horror:
displayGenre(allSeries, "Horror")
```

Then you can use `type` variable in the function as well.

Comment: Simple as that, I couldn't see it before. Thank you for your help!